# Wordpress rebuild - 301 redirect old pages (*.php) to pretty permalinks

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is what I need to do:

old pages are mydomain.com/something.php

new pages are rebuilt in Wordpress identified using pretty permalinks so they are mydomain.com/something/

I need to figure out what the rewrite rule should look like.  I have crawled the web and can't find anything exactly like it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^(.*)\.php$ $1/ [R=permanent]
```

The (.*) is a "group" of characters before the .php, and $1 refers to that group of characters.  So just add a slash to the group and send the browser to the new URL with an HTTP code 301 (permanent redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Ignore index.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(wp-login|wp-admin|wp-includes)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1/ [R=301,L]

#"Standard" Wordpress Rewrite Stuff
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/catalog
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```